# Refresh a Fusion block on click of a button wordpress Avada

Tags: ajax, wordpress, partial-page-refresh

I have some buttons on a page and on click of each button the page gets reload and the data changes. Now, I would like to refresh that particular fusion block only without reloading the page. The buttons are added to the page as a widget (with some valid reasons) and the fusion block is on the page itself. Would it be possible to achieve what I am looking for?